# How to avoid babel's 'Uncaught ReferenceError: stringClasses is not defined'?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I have a javascript code that I want to minify. I'm using gulp tasks to do it:

```
...
gulp.task('app.js', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/assets/js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['env']}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/public/js'))
})
...
```

But I noticed that I was having a javascript error when tried to access the page that loads html with this minified javascript:

```sh
Uncaught ReferenceError: stringClasses is not defined
    at newElement (jv.js:1)
    at new Screen (jv.js:1)
    at HashGame (jv.js:1)
    at jv.js:1
```

So I thought that was a problem from `uglify()` function and delete the uglify step but the problem continues (so the problem is babel):

```sh
Uncaught ReferenceError: stringClasses is not defined
    at newElement (jv.js:12)
    at new Screen (jv.js:137)
    at HashGame (jv.js:153)
    at jv.js:162
```

The original newElement function is:

```
function Item(id){
    this.elem = newElement('div', 'item', 'pencilBorder')
    this.elem.id = id
    this.play = (checker) => {
        if (!this.elem.attributes.filled){
            this.elem.innerHTML = 'X'
            this.elem.attributes.value = 'X'
            this.elem.setAttribute("filled", true)
            if (!checker.check()){
                robotPlay()
                checker.check()
            }
        }
    }
    this.elem.onclick = (e) => {
        this.play(new Checker())
    }
}
```

and babel is changing it to:

```
function newElement(tagName) {
    var elem = document.createElement(tagName);

    for (var _len = arguments.length, classNames = Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
        classNames[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
    }

    stringClasses = classNames.reduce(function (ac, current) {
        return ac + " " + current;
    });
    elem.className = stringClasses;
    return elem;
}
```

I've searched for babel options and tried new presets but nothing worked. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem: it was my function `newElement`.

I declared the variable stringClasses without var/let or const before it and it works if I don't use babel. But when babel changes it for es2015 this turns on a problem.